# Gaussian integers quotients vs polynomial ring quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've seen that in the Gaussian integers we have the isomorphism:

$$ \frac{\mathbb{Z[i]}}{(f(i))} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(f(X),X^2+1)} $$

Where $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. In small cases I've seen this isomorphism with the ring isomorphism theorems. However, I'm not sure this happens for every $f$.

I think that the ring morphism $X \rightarrow i$ should be an isomorphism. As I'm new to this topic I wanted to know if my reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "In small cases I've seen this isomorphism with the ring isomorphism theorems. However, I'm not sure this happens for every f."

**Answer:** This is one of the "isomorphism theorems": When you write $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(f(i))$ you mean the ring $(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1))/(f(\overline{x}))$ where $f(\overline{x})\in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$. It follows there is an inclusion of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

$$I:=(x^2+1) \subseteq (x^2+1,f(x)):=J$$ and isomorphisms

$$\mathbb{Z}[i]/(f(i)) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/I)/(J/I) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/J :=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,f(x)).$$

Comment: Oh I think I was missing the part that the $(f(\bar{x}))$ is an ideal on $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with the relation $x^2+1=0$. Then, we have that $(f(\bar{x})) = J/I$.

Answer (score 0):

When $R$ is a commutative ring, and $x,y \in R$, the principal ideal of $R/(x)$ generated by $\overline y := y+(x)$, namely $(\overline y)$, coincides with $(x,y)/(x)$, as you can check. Thus, the  third isomorphism theorem (see 5 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_C_(rings))) tells us that $$\frac{R/(x)}{(\overline y)} = \frac{R/(x)}{(x,y)/(x)} \cong \frac R{(x,y)}.$$

Hence, for $p \in \mathbb Z[X]$, $$\frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{(X^2+1,p)} \cong \frac{\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)}{(\overline p)}.$$

Now, it is well-known that $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb Z[i] := \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$ via the map that sends $\overline q \in \mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$ to $q(i)$. Therefore, under this isomorphism, the ideal $(\overline p)$ corresponds to the ideal $(p(i))$, which means that

$$\frac{\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)}{(\overline p)} \cong \frac{\mathbb Z[i]}{(p(i))}.$$